# Framework hibernate-generic-dao NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, nullpointerexception, dao

i using the hibernate-generic-dao framework: https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/. But i can not persist, or read any object. 
Allways i execute some method inherited from GenericDAOImpl, cause a NullPointerException.

I read some post's that says that the problem can be that I'm not setting up the sessionFactory, 
the framework doesn't do this? If it is the case, how implements this?

This is my interface inheriting the GenericDAO interface:

```
public interface EnterpriseDAO extends GenericDAO<Enterprise, String>{
}
```

This is my specific DAO implementation:

```
public class EnterpriseDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Enterprise, String>
    implements EnterpriseDAO{
}
```

And with this code i try to persist an object:

```
    EnterpriseDAO dao = new EnterpriseDAOImpl();

    Enterprise enterprise1 = new Enterprise();
    enterprise1.setUniqueId("a.0.0.0.1");
    enterprise1.setName("Empresa2");
    enterprise1.setTaxId("125-565465-564");
    enterprise1.setUserName("a.0.0.0.1");
    enterprise1.setPassword("password");

    boolean exito = dao.save(enterprise1);
    System.out.println("Se guardo: " + exito);
```

I hope that can help me,i dont find the way or see the error. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the SessionFactory in your DAO ?

I'm using Spring with hibernate-generic-dao and my daos look like :

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Employee, Long> {

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

...

}
```

Comment: Yes i have config the sessionFactory in my Implemented class, but i not using Spring and CDI, how I set the sessionFactory manually? because you are injected this object.

Comment: You usually create a HibernateUtil class that will build the SessionFactory and expose it to the rest of your code. Just google HibernateUtil and you should find what you are looking for
for example: http://www.bullraider.com/java/hibernate-36/tutorials/67-crud-in-hibernate

Comment: Yes i know that, so i have to create the HibernateUtil and pass in the constructor per example?

Comment: You don't really need to pass the HibernateUtil to the constructor, generally HibernateUtil has a static method to get a SessionFactory. You could do something like this is in the constructor of your dao super.setSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory());

Comment: I can not implement the framework, so i made my own DAO, with the way that put in the last comment, thnaks any way!!